# Loop over test patterns in Verilog testbench

Tags: loops, verilog

First day struggling with verilog, here is a simple module:

```
module example4_23 (x, f);
  input [0:6] x;
  output f;

  assign f = x[0] & x[1] & x[2] & x[3] & x[4] & x[5] & x[6];
endmodule
```

Then I want to write a testbench for it. Firstly, I used 7bit register for x (no array) - everything worked, but now i want to run it with several test patterns, so I announce an array and want to loop over it and run the module with new input every time.

```
module test;
  reg [0:6] arr [0:1] = {7'b0011111,7'b1100000}; // all patterns
  reg [0:1] arr_size;                            // number of patterns
  wire [0:6] x;                                  // current pattern
  wire f;                                        // output

  initial begin
    $write("| TIME | x0 | x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | x5 | x6 |   f   |"); // header
    $display;
    arr_size = $size(arr);                                         // 2
  end

// go through all test patterns, assign it to x and run the module   
  genvar i;  
  generate
    for (i=0; i<2; i=i+1)         // if use 'i<arr_size' gives an error
    begin
      assign x = arr[i];  // change to '..= arr[1]' or '..= arr[0]' successfully makes one test
      example4_23 dut (x,f);
    end
  endgenerate

// anytime there is a change - output on the screen   
  always @(x,f)
  begin
    $strobe("%6d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %5d", $time, x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5],x[6], f);
  end

endmodule
```

Currently after compiling I only see the header line. Except an obvious question, why it doesnt work, I also dont understand the following:

1. What should I use for x - wire or register?
2. Can I get without the 'generate'\'for' cycle? Probably there is a way to simplify the code.
3. Is it possible to use a variable arr_size in FOR cycle instead of a number?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised you don't get an error about assigning multiple values to `f`.

Remember that verilog (or any other HDL) creates physical circuits, and a generate block creates multiple versions of a given circuit. In this case, you're creating two instances of your `example4_23` module and have both driving the same output. `Generate` loops operate in a spatial manner, while for loops in an `always` block are temporal when you add delays.

To answer your questions: 1) use a `reg`, and assign the value in an `always` block with a delay; 2) Yes! (see below example); 3) Yes! Use a parameter!

So, here's some changes you could make:

- replace `wire arr_size` with a `localparam ARR_SIZE = 2` (or as appropriate)
- change `reg [0:6] arr [0:1]` to `reg [0:6] arr [0:ARR_SIZE1-]`
- replace the `generate` loop with a basic for loop in an `initial` block
- The array of test vectors could be a parameter instead of a wire or reg
- Add in delays. Right now, your test bench doesn't vary with time, only in space. Delays are noted using a `#` (see below)
- Use `always @(*)` instead of `always @(x,f)`

Here's what I would implement:

```
module test;
  localparam ARR_SIZE = 2;                            // number of patterns
  localparam [0:6] arr [0:ARR_SIZE-1] = {7'b0011111,7'b1100000}; // all patterns
  reg[0:6] x;                                  // current pattern
  wire f;                                        // output
  integer i;

  example4_23 dut (x,f);  

  initial begin
    $write("| TIME | x0 | x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | x5 | x6 |   f   |"); // header
    $display;
    for (i=0; i< ARR_SIZE; i=i+1) begin
      x = arr[i];
      #5;    // delay 5 timesteps
    end
  end

// anytime there is a change - output on the screen   
  always @(*)
  begin
    $strobe("%6d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %5d", $time, x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5],x[6], f);
  end

endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you! One more question...

Initial starts first, assigns x and during the delay always block reacts on the change and prints the data. then again change, delay and print.Could you explain at which moments is the tested module executed? I have read that all code should be included in either initial or always statements. But here it is not the case.

Comment: Remember that verilog describes physical circuits, which means the modules always exist. As such, the test module will constantly evaluate the inputs, and nothing is "executed" like in programming. However, the strobe will only display when the inputs or output change, which occurs every 5 timesteps (the #5).